# Tagging items in an image

Tags: flutter

I want to take a pic or choose from the gallery and then then label each item in the pic.

i am able to take the pic and also choose from gallery but have no idea on how to go on with the labelling/ tagging part.

Comment: You can use Image Labeling from Firebase ML Vision to recognize what is in the picture and add labels with custom painter